# Specifying exact Python version for Travis CI in combination with tox

Tags: python, travis-ci, tox

I have the following .travis.yml:

```
language: python

env:
  - TOXENV=py27
  - TOXENV=py34

install:
  - pip install -U tox

script:
  - tox
```

and the following tox.ini:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27,py34

[testenv]
commands = py.test tests/
deps = -rtests/test_requirements.txt
```

I need Python 3.4.3, which is [available since awhile back](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4632) in Travis. How can I specify this exact version of Python in .travis.yml so tox can use the correct version for the `py34` environment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inspired by `pip`'s [.travis.yml](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/166f3d20e27f06c1ca74d30ec6ceed688f295b47/.travis.yml) it seems easiest to specify the Travis matrix with different environment variables:

```
matrix:
    include:
        - python: 3.4.3
          env: TOXENV=py34
        - python: 2.7
          env: TOXENV=py27
```